# How can :erlang.length([some, list, data]) raise an ArgumentError

Tags: elixir

I've got a system that does a job by collating thousands of API calls. Non-deterministically to the initial job inputs, the following will sometimes be logged:

`11:31:05.977 [error] GenServer {:n, :l, {"11:25:04.914262am", :collector}} terminating
** (ArgumentError) argument error
    :erlang.length([%HTTPoison.Response ... (truncated)`

How can the prefix `:erlang.length([%HTTPoison.Response` be completed such that it emits a runtime ArgumentError?

Comment: The only reason I can think of is that you have an "improper list".

Comment: That's a great idea. My first thought is this is impossible here because that list is only constructed in one place and it works most of the time. I'll study it.

Comment: I can see a path where it could happen now, so you must be right. Add an answer and I'll mark it resolved.

Comment: Looks like someone else did that before me. You can accept that. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`erlang:length/1` will raise a bad argument (ArgumentError in your case) when the value passed in is not a proper list.

It could be that you passed in an entirely different type of value, or you may have an improper list. From the error message in your question it's most likely due to an improper list.